# How to get all class name at once form a HTML file to a CSS file

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML file and its mockup. Pulling the class name from the HTML file to the CSS file is pain full process. is there any way to get all the class names in a CSS file at once?

Comment: need to declare a mutual class name for all the elements or have utility classes.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33027291/1851678) answer your question? You can just change the output format to write to a CSS file.

Comment: what's your editor? that's vscode?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is an extension for this it is called **evondev**.

Here is my snippet that might work :

```js
var html = "bla<p class='c1 c2'>blabla<button></button><div id='bla' class='c1 c3'></div>";

var classes = []; // empty array

html.replace(/class=['"][^'"]+/g, function(m){ // https://regex101.com/r/jD0wX1/1
    classes = classes.concat(m.match(/[^'"]+$/)[0].split(' ')); // https://regex101.com/r/jD0wX1/2
}); // take all classes

classes = classes.filter(function(item, pos) {
    return classes.indexOf(item) == pos;
}); // return unique classes

console.log(classes); // Run code snippet -> then press f12 to see the array
```

Try and Implement it. Feel free to ask for help in the comments

Answer (score 1):

Maybe work in an advanced code editor like VS code which will make it easier for you to import class names with the help of autocomplete feature.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33377488)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
function extract(html) {
  let m= html.match(/class=(".*?"|'.*?')/g)||[];            // class list
  let c= m.map(c=>c.replace(/class=("|')/,'').slice(0,-1)); // only names
  let dedup= [...new Set(c.map(x=>x.split` `).flat())];     // del duplicates

  return dedup.reduce((a,c) => a+=`.${c} {\n}\n\n`, '')
}
```

```html
<textarea id="inp" cols="70" rows="4" placeholder="Paste html"></textarea>
<br><button onclick="output.value=extract(inp.value)">Extract CSS!</button>
<br><br><textarea id="output" cols="70" rows="4"></textarea>
```